# Get multiple CSS filter values with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-filters

Considering the following inline CSS on an image...

```
<img class="selectedImg" style="-webkit-filter:grayscale(22%) blur(2px) brightness(91%) contrast(120%) hue-rotate(29deg) opacity(86%) invert(15%) saturate(261%) sepia(30%)" src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/"/>
```

...how can I use jQuery/javscript to read the values and put each in a variable to achieve this as a result?

```
var gs = '22',
    blur = '2',
    brightness = '91',
    contrast = '120',
    hue = '29',
    opacity = '86',
    invert = '15',
    saturate = '261',
    sepia = '30'
```

What I have started: http://jsfiddle.net/kthornbloom/fvp9d732/2/

Comment: Try to catch -webkit-filter to a string and then use slice() to get each parameter.   string.slice(' ')  will give you array ['grayscale(22%)', 'blur(2px)', ...]. then you can again do for each of them slice('(') or other characters. Just figure out what will be the fastest.

Comment: @Sko you sure about that with slice()? I think you mixed up your string methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters you can start with:-

```
var filters = $('.selectedImg').css('-webkit-filter');
```

instead of:

```
var filters = $('selectedImg').css('webkitFilter');
```

You forgot to add `.` prefix for class and also the css key value was not correct.

Moving forward you can split the `filters` variable by space like:-

```
var arr = filters.split(" ");
```

This will give you an array like:-

```
["grayscale(0.22)", "blur(2px)", "brightness(0.91)", "contrast(1.2)", "hue-rotate(29deg)", "opacity(0.86)", "invert(0.15)", "saturate(2.61)", "sepia(0.3)"]
```

Next you can set it like:-

```
var gs = arr[0],
    blur = arr[1],
    brightness = arr[2],
    contrast = arr[3],
    hue = arr[4],
    opacity = arr[5],
    invert = arr[6],
    saturate = arr[7],
    sepia = arr[8];
```

You will need to filter the values here though. I hope you can take it from here.

Comment: Thank you, can't believe I missed the period on the class name. Yes I can take it from here.